# How can I get root to work for system app in Android?

Tags: android, linux

I need to mount nfs share from the system app to sdcard or to mnt folder, but `mount` works only with root access granted. How can I do this? (This is not only the one program, that not work without root. For example, I also need root to use `dd` to flash custom recovery on my system)

I downloaded AOSP Marshmallow sources, I added su and all it needs to /system/xbin folder. When I try to run `su` it prints me `"Permission denied"`, but via `adb shell` root works normally (I can run it in xbin folder). What permissions I need to add to run my system apps as root? Thanks.

System and system apps built and signed with the platform key. App that I am testing has `sharedUid=android.uid.system` property in `Manifest.xml`

Comment: You need to install supersu or equivalent.

Comment: supersu installed, but without apk. I do not want the other apps can gain root, I want get root only for some platform apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution that works for me is the server binary that launched by `init` as root process. I wrote simple server binary that can be connected via `LocalSocket` from java side and I can send it some commands. To start server binary on system start, I added next lines to `init.rc` script:

```
service suservice /system/bin/suservice
   class core
   user root
   group root
   socket suservice stream 0600 system system
```

On java side I wrote simple library that works via callback interface and receives data from this service or error if something wrong.

Now only apps that started as `system:system` can use this local socket to run root commands. User apps receive `Permission denied` as expexted.

P.S. There is no need to run or keep `su` binary now at all, because server binary already runs as root. I can completly remove `su` binary from the system now.

Comment: Hi, your solution has pointed me to the right direction. I've setup everything but I'm receiving a "permission denied error" on the Java side. Any idea why? For testing purposes, I've set the socket permission to "0666 system system" so that I can debug my app as a regular app. Many thx!

Comment: Hello, try to disable SELinux first, because it may blocks most of the root operations. It can be disabled via "setenforce 0" command in the shell as  a root user. If You see "[audit]" messages in logcat before "Permission denied" message - it is problem in SELinux and You need add SELinux permissions for "suservice", recompile Your kernel and reflash it.

Comment: Just realized my socket permission stayed as 0600 somehow. Needed to flash boot from recovery mode instead. But I'm seeing a different error now. "Connection refused". My SELinux is on permissive and there is no "[audit]" related message. Guess SElinux is not the issue. Netstat shows my socket is active, "unix  2      [ ]         STREAM                     9238 /dev/socket/tcpdump_nc".

Comment: Sorry, I think I just lied. After checking kmsg, I'm seeing a few lines with "audit" related message. Gonna try modifying my kernel...

Comment: Hi I'm back again... so I added SELinux permission to the socket file but the [audit] message seems to be gone now in in kmsg. But i'm still seeing the same "Connection refused" error. I posted my question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124623/android-init-rc-service-socket-data-stream-connection-refused. thx!

Comment: I don't know how to get it to work from binary files, but to get it to work from apk (Java) You need to sign Your apk with your platform key and start this app with system UID (android.uid.system in AndroidManifest.xml). In other situations there will be "Connection refused" error. Also check if this socket is created in the file system, if it is not created - "Connection refused" error will appear.

Comment: Sorry for the numerous questions. How do you have your suservice to listen on the socket file? In the init.rc readme file, it says the socket returns a file descriptor to the launched process. I'm guessing your suservice is taking this file descriptor and write data to it? this is probably where I'm missing. All I did was to echo output to stdout instead of the file descriptor. I'm using shell script instead of writing C code. How would you achieve it in shell script?

Comment: Suservice listens to this socket and launches commands that I write into the socket. Because this process starts from the root user I can noramally run commands in it. I can give You an example how to do It in C code, but I think there is no way to do it in shell script. If You give me some of Your contact data, I'll send You an exmaple based on my code.

Comment: ya, that's what I suspected. It would be great if you could send me a sample. You can send it to jiberishgeek@gmail.com. I have been trying to find source code for their build-in program such as logd and figure out how they did it. But no luck yet... Thx in advance. You are awesome!

Answer (score 3):

`su` as provided by AOSP has restrictions built it to ensure you are the root or shell user invoking it. This check is at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/su/su.c#85

You could always add the system UID (`AID_SYSTEM`) to this check; however, this would pose a security risk by granting blanket root privileges to all apps/process with the system UID. I would only add the system user to this line in `su.c` if you are accepting those risks and want an easy solution.

I would recommend re-evaluating your use case and potentially write a native daemon/service that exposes an function for applications to only perform the actions required. You could then enforce these with higher-level android permissions, as well as, POSIX capabilities for the native daemon itself.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to add this to my post - I already add AID_SYSTEM to su file, but after that I got an error "Operation not permitted" on setgid and setuid functions. Only apps and services that already running as root can run this functions without any problem.

Comment: Any progress with that?