# Android init.rc service socket data stream, "Connection Refused"

Tags: android, linux, sockets

I'm working on a project to get network data using tcpdump. To simplify the problem, let's replace tcpdump with a script I wrote.

```
#!/system/bin/sh
while :
do
     echo print out from socket
     sleep 1
done
```

I put it under /system/xbin/echo_test on my phone

```
-rwxr-xr-x root     root           70 2017-02-08 12:15 echo_test
```

so when I type in my command, "echo_test", it constantly prints out "print out from socket" to simulate the data.

Now the real deal, to run this script from a service and stream data through socket when the phone boots, I took the boot image and modified the ramdisk.

In the init.rc file, I added the following lines.

```
service echo_test /system/xbin/echo_test
     user root
     group root
     class late_start
     seclabel u:r:init:s0
     socket echo_test stream 0666 system system
```

In the file_contexts file, I added my socket file with a existing SELinux context.

```
/dev/socket/echo_test   u:object_r:logd_socket:s0
```

I picked logd_socket because there seems to be an existing logd socket file (if I'm doing it wrong here, please let me know...)

```
/dev/socket/logd    u:object_r:logd_socket:s0
```

Then I repackaged the boot image and flashed back to the phone. The phone boots without any issue. But when I test the socket with netcat, I'm receiving "Connection Refused" error. I got the same error when I try to access the socket from Java.

```
root@hammerhead:/ # netcat -U /dev/socket/echo_test                                               
Ncat: Connection refused.
```

Netcat behaves okay on other unix domain socket,

```
root@hammerhead:/ # netcat -U /dev/socket/logd                                               
500 Command too large for buffer
```

Check the kmsg only give me this line:

```
root@hammerhead:/ # cat /proc/kmsg | grep echo_test
<5>[    3.409779] init: Starting service 'echo_test'...
```

Netstat also shows the socket is active.

```
root@hammerhead:/ $ netstat | grep echo_test
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM                     6360         /dev/socket/echo_test
```

Here is the socket file permission,

```
srw-rw-rw- system   system            u:object_r:logd_socket:s0 echo_test
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

edit:

I'm using Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1